# Find a two variables function given some values

Tags: analysis, polynomials, interpolation

I have a question. I have to find, for example, a function $f(s,t)$ of $s,t \in [0;1]$ such that : $f(0,t)=1, f(1,t)=0, f(s,1)=0$, but I don't succeed to find it.

In general, given a function of multivariables and some values at some points, is there a method in order to determine a function which verify the conditions ? If it was in 1 variable, I thought about Lagrange polynomial, but in multivariable case, how to do ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible of course.

For $t=1$ you get $f(0,1)=1$, for $s=0$ you get $f(0,1)=0$.

Comment: It's a fail for the example... But the question is still the same in general, is there a method to find a function of two variables or more, which verify $f(x_i,y_i)=z_i$ of some $i \in \{0,1,...,n\}$ ?

Comment: @ChocoSavour This is not really your question. Your question is about infinitely many constraints. Perhaps you should write another question? I don't know how to answer the one in your comment.

Comment: Yes, I think it's wasn't even clear for myself. Anyway, thank you for your answer.